# Matlab: cutting out a shape from an image based on X and Y coordinates

Tags: image, matlab, shapes

Is there a way to automatically cut out a shape from a image in Matlab 2015a based on provided X and Y coordinates?

`antenna.Polygon` seems to do that, however that's a function for Matlab 2018a.

Comment: [`imcrop`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html)

Comment: [`antenna.Polygon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/antenna/ref/antenna.polygon.html) was introduced in R2017a; not R2018a

Comment: @SardarUsama can you please elaborate? `J = imcrop(I,rect)` is not what I'm looking for as I'm not looking to use an rectangle. `J = imcrop(x,y,___) ` makes sense however I'm not sure how to use the syntax. Something like `J = imcrop([x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3], image) ` does not crop the image, it kind of squishes it.

Comment: The documentation is written in detail with examples. You need to transform your data according to the function. What you already have for `rect` are  `x1` and `y1`. You need to calculate `width` and `height` which is the difference between  `x2` and `x1`, and `y2` and `y1` respectively.

Comment: @SardarUsama Isn't `rect` for cutting out rectangles? I'm trying to cut out a triangle.

Comment: That's an important information left out in your question

Comment: @SardarUsama I'm sorry about that. [Here's](http://oi64.tinypic.com/2a4s7bs.jpg) an sample image with the shape I'm trying to cut out shown with yellow lines. I will have access to the `x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3` coordinates.

Comment: After cropping what will you have? An image is a matrix and therefore it has to be a rectangular shape. You can have a mask with that cropped triangle. Is this the result that you're expecting?

Comment: @SardarUsama You're right, a mask is what I was looking for! I managed to do what I hoped for with `createMask` and `impoly`. Thank you for leading me in the right direction and for the patience.

Comment: You can post that as an answer to help future visitors with the same problem